# Crystal Reports Server 2011 character set compatibility

Tags: crystal-reports, collation, crystal-reports-server, collate

I'm currently working on SQL Server 2008 R2 and plan to get Crystal Reports Server 2011 up and running with SQL Server.  Wanted to see if Crystal Reports Server 2011 supports the Latin-1 general character set collation.  Just wanting to make sure that SQL Server and Crystal Reports Server are both compatible with Latin-1.

Thanks so much!